# TypeError at /news/ , html() takes no arguments

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am a beginner in Django. Can you guys tell me why I am getting this error. 
code:

```
enter code here:
import feedparser
from django.http import HttpResponse

def news():
    YahooContent = feedparser.parse ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/")
    for feed in YahooContent.entries:
        print feed.published
        print feed.title
        print feed.link + "\n"
   return

def html():
    html = "<html><body> %s </body></html>" % news()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /news/
html() takes no arguments (1 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    this is not a url : (http://djangodefault.com:8000/news/)
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
html() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#writing-views):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that
>   takes a Web request and returns a Web response.

In other words, your function(s) should accept a `request` argument:

```
def html(request):
    html = "<html><body> %s </body></html>" % news()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: @AmirNakhostin ok, your `news()` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: is itnt supposed to print the three lines? how do I fix it?

Comment: The [third part of the Dajango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) covers the creation of HTML pages with templates.

Comment: @AmirNakhostin This answer has solved the problem, please accept it.